# Trying to get property of non-object (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy con un proyecto en Laravel, soy bastante novata en esto (de hecho es mi primer proyecto). Es una página de blog y quiero mostrar los post como si fuera una especie de plantilla.

Tengo un array en el controller:

```
public function blog()
{
    $elementos=[];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $item = new \stdClass();
        $item->tema = $i . "Lorem ipsum";
        $item->titulo = $i . "Lorem ipsum";
        $item->time = $i . "Lorem ipsum";
        array_push($elementos,(object) $item);
    }
   

return view('saasbox.blog.portadablog2', compact('elementos',));
}
```

Y luego en foreach en la vista:

```
 @foreach ($elementos as $elemento)
      <!-- Single Blog Post-->
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="card blog-card border-0 no-boxshadow rounded-0"><a class="d-block mb-4" href="blog-card.html"><img src="img/bg-img/blog4.jpg" alt=""></a>
          <div class="post-content"><a class="d-block mb-1" href="blog-card.html">{{ $elemento->tema }}</a><a class="post-title d-block mb-3" href="blog-card.html">
              <h4>{{ $elemento->titulo }}</h4></a>
            <div class="post-meta"><span class="text-muted">{{ $elemento->time }}</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
       
      </div>
      @endforeach
```

Y así tengo puesta las rutas en web.php

```
        Route::group(
            [
            'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale()
            ],
            function()
                {
                Route::get('/blog2', 'BlogController2@blog')->name('blog/portadablog2');
                });
```

No sé en qué estoy fallando o cómo podría hacerlo pero no hay manera de que me muestre en la vista la estructura del post. Gracias.

Lo que quiero es que el array saque en la vista "i" la estructura de la prevista de los posts.

Answer (score 1):

Verifiqué tu código y tengo los siguientes observaciones, así como algunos consejos.

- En tu vista, estás tratando de acceder a propiedades desde el arreglo principal. Lo que tienes es `$elementos->titulo`, lo que hace que busque una propiedad de un arreglo, la cual no existe.
- Cuando usas un `foreach($elementos as $elemento)` recuerda que `$elementos` es tu arreglo principal y `$elemento` es lo que va a estar tomando en el ciclo actual, tomando automática el siguiente elemento de la lista. Si te fijas, en tu ejemplo no usas la variable `$elemento`. Esa variable es por la cual deberías acceder a las propiedades, de la manera `$elemento->titulo`.

Otro par de consejos que te puedo dar, están en la parte de tu controlador.

- Veo que debería de existir una entidad llamada `Blog` entonces, idealmente, podrías crear un modelo de Laravel `Blog` y tu `BlogController`
- Además de escoger un nombre más claro para el método que vas a usar, por ejemplo, si vas a mostrar una lista de Blogs, podrías llamarlo el método `index()` de tu Blog Controller y, por ejemplo, si vas a mostrar uno es específico, podrías llamarlo  el método `show()` de tu Blog Controller. Todo esto a manera de tener buenas prácticas y, por ende, mejor código.

Comment: cambié "elementos" por "elemento" y aún así sigue saliendo el mismo error. Lo que quiero es listar los posts de un blog que se vea la foto, la categoría, el título y el tiempo de lectura. Discúlpame pero estoy dando mis primeros pasos en Laravel y me siento un poco perdida.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Hola me parece que en tu controlador estas creando tus objetos pero los almacenas en un array, por lo tanto para acceder a ellos seria

```
@foreach ($elementos as $elemento)
  <!-- Single Blog Post-->
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card blog-card border-0 no-boxshadow rounded-0"><a class="d-block mb-4" href="blog-card.html"><img src="img/bg-img/blog4.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <div class="post-content"><a class="d-block mb-1" href="blog-card.html">{{ $elemento['tema'] }}</a><a class="post-title d-block mb-3" href="blog-card.html">
          <h4>{{ $elemento['titulo'] }}</h4></a>
        <div class="post-meta"><span class="text-muted">{{ $elemento['time'] }}</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>       
  </div>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo error :(. ¿Puede ser que el error me venga del web.php y la manera que tengo puesta la ruta? (lo he añadido en el principal)
                    });
                  `

Comment: Si almacena objetos entonces si debe iterar el array pero el acceso a las claves es con ->

Comment: pues depende de el tipo de envió que realices, ya que puedes hacerlo con directamente con php o con las funciones que brinda laravel y en cada caso cambia la manera en que accedes a los datos